# Como tratar a exigência de certos atributos em modelos que incluam um concern no Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testes-de-unidade

Estou trabalhando em um projeto onde tenho vários modelos que compartilham o comportamento de serem *approváveis*. Depois de pesquisar um pouco, cheguei a conclusão de que o melhor neste caso é utilizar o padrão de *concerns* com a ajuda do **ActiveSupport::Concern**. Confesso que realmente não consegui encontrar muita diferença em relação ao que outras linguagens já fazem com o uso de interfaces, se alguém puder me esclarecer melhor sobre isso; agradeço. Indo direto ao ponto, meu *concern* batizado de *Approvable* é o seguinte:

```
module Approvable
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
            #validations
            validates :approval_status,
                    presence: true,
                    inclusion: { :in => NixusValidation::ValidApprovalStatuses, :message => :inclusion, unless: 'approval_status.blank?' }
            #scopes:
            scope :approved, -> { where(approvalStatus: NixusValidation::ApprovalStatuses::APPROVED) }
            scope :pending, -> { where(approvalStatus: NixusValidation::ApprovalStatuses::PENDING) }
            scope :unapproved, -> { where(approvalStatus: NixusValidation::ApprovalStatuses::UNAPPROVED) }
    end

    #INSTANCE METHODS
    #methods:
    def approved?()
            self.approval_status == NixusValidation::ApprovalStatuses::APPROVED
    end
end
```

Ainda estão pendentes alguns compartamentos, como "aprovar" e "desaprovar", mas minha dúvida consiste no seguinte, toda modelo aprovável vai precisar possuir e persistir um atributo approval_status. Como modelar isso sem o uso de herança? O jeito "certo" é simplesmente saber que todo modelo aprovável deve incluir este atributo? Como desenhar os testes? Crio um objeto simples que inclua o módulo?

Answer (score 1):

Simples, antes do ActiveSupport::Concerns você precisava incluir um módulo de uma lib, no ActiveRecord para poder fazer uso de um comportamento, por exemplo:

```
User.my_custom_method
```

Concerns, veio para ajudar nesse sentido, pois concentramos em escrever nossos módulos e apenas incluímos eles nos Models que compartilha os comportamentos. A Maneira correta de se fazer isso é justamente com Modules que tem o conceito de ser algo reaproveitável que injetamos em algum cliente que a utiliza (em outras linguagens faríamos isso atrávez de DI (Dependency Injection)). Herança conceitualmente é algo que deve ser compartilhado apenas para 'coisas' que são do mesmo tipo, o que não se aplica ao seu caso, pois você está aproveitando o comportamento aproval_status em tipos diferentes.

Para modelar isso sem uso de herança(que no caso é mais correto) utilize os Concerns como vem fazendo e apenas inclua o Module nos Models que precisar fazer uso do comportamento que deseja compartilhar:

```
class User
  include Approvable
end
```

E o seu model User terá o comportamento:

```
User.approved?
```

Para testar você deve criar os arquivos no diretório de testes igual você criou na pasta app. E testar o seu módulo isoladamente.

app path

```
app/models/concerns/aprovabble.rb
```

test path

```
spec/models/concerns/approvabble_spec.rb
```

E em seguida testar os módulos que fazem uso do comportamento compartilhado, por exemplo em: spec/models/user_spec.rb

```
expect(User.approved?).to eq(true)
```